# Rails active_record_extended - With undefined method `with' for #<Class:0x00007f981bbb7118>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to use the gem "active_record_extended", so I have added to Gemfile and run "bundle".

```
gem 'active_record_extended'
```

Now if I try

```
irb(main):002:0> User.with
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):1
        1: from (irb):2:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `with' for #<Class:0x00007fc6f43df208>)
```

Should I require the gem somewhere? I have tried to required from application.rb but I got the problem.

**config/application.rb**

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

# CUSTOM
require "active_record_extended"
```

If I try this from Rails console

```
irb(main):002:0> require "active_record_extended"
=> false
```

Gemfile.lock

```
active_record_extended (1.4.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.0, < 6.1)
      ar_outer_joins (~> 0.2)
      pg (< 2.0)
activerecord (6.0.3.4)
  activemodel (= 6.0.3.4)
  activesupport (= 6.0.3.4)
activerecord-import (1.0.7)
  activerecord (>= 3.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For future references, for some reason this gem won't work if you don't put it in a group. I did

```
group :development, :test, :staging, :production do
  gem 'active_record_extended'
end
```

And it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I think after `bundle install` you have not **restarted** the rails console, that's why it is not letting you use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding some info within the `with` method.

like in the documentation `User.with(highly_liked: ProfileL.where("likes > 300"))`

Comment: yes, same error.  If I run "require "active_record_extended" in the rails console I get false. Shouldn't it be true?

Comment: Try deleting the `gemfile.lock` and reinstalling the gem, I tried and its working for me, and in the `rails console` im getting `false` too

Comment: And also check that your postgresql is on the latest version

Comment: Done. Same error. Postgres 13 (using Postgres.app). Added new Gem file.lock

Comment: I have removed gem "activerecord-import" now i get NoMethodError (undefined method `with' for Profile (call 'Profile.connection' to establish a connection):Class) for Profile.with(test: Profile.all)

Comment: run `Profile.connection` in rails console.

Comment: I get "#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter:0x00007f7f9697ba40"....

Comment: Now run `Profile.with` or `User.with`

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `with' for #<Class:0x00007fa8f7f7c5b8>)